# manual pages of built .deb install on Debian but not Ubuntu

Tags: debian, ubuntu, dpkg, man, deb

I am testing out the build of a `.deb` package on different distributions using test-kitchen. The built `.deb` file installs the command to `/usr/bin` fine on both Debian and Ubuntu. My problem is that the man pages don't get installed on Ubuntu. The contents of the built `.deb` file on Ubuntu is:

```
kitchen@ceddd8d3564c:/opt/workspace$ dpkg -c $(find . -name \*.deb)
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0           33742 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/bin/git-secret
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man7/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            5298 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man7/git-secret.7
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1355 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-add.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             819 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-init.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1440 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-hide.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1734 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-tell.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             931 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-clean.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             936 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-remove.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             959 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-list.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1246 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-cat.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             843 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-usage.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1337 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-reveal.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1445 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-changes.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             998 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-killperson.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             940 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-whoknows.1
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/doc/git-secret/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             149 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/doc/git-secret/changelog.gz
kitchen@ceddd8d3564c:/opt/workspace$
```

The install command is `sudo dpkg --force-all --install $(find . -name \*.deb)` which outputs:

```
(Reading database ... 41209 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../git-secret_0.2.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking git-secret (0.2.4) over (0.2.4) ...
Setting up git-secret (0.2.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
```

After that the `man git-secret` and `man git-secret-init` report "No manual entry for git-secret-init".

Things are working on Debian latest with the same package:

```
kitchen@c71479c4f76c:/opt/workspace$ dpkg -c $(find . -name \*.deb)
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0           33742 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/bin/git-secret
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man7/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            5298 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man7/git-secret.7
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1355 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-add.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             819 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-init.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1440 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-hide.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1734 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-tell.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             931 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-clean.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             936 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-remove.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             959 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-list.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1246 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-cat.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             843 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-usage.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1337 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-reveal.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1445 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-changes.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             998 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-killperson.1
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             940 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-whoknows.1
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/doc/git-secret/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             149 2018-06-08 14:24 ./usr/share/doc/git-secret/changelog.gz
kitchen@c71479c4f76c:/opt/workspace$
```

Installed the same way:

```
kitchen@c71479c4f76c:/opt/workspace$ sudo dpkg --force-all --install $(find . -name \*.deb)
Selecting previously unselected package git-secret.
(Reading database ... 29069 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../git-secret_0.2.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking git-secret (0.2.4) ...
Setting up git-secret (0.2.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
kitchen@c71479c4f76c:/opt/workspace$
```

Works:

```
kitchen@c71479c4f76c:/opt/workspace$ man -w git-secret-init
/usr/share/man/man1/git-secret-init.1
kitchen@c71479c4f76c:/opt/workspace$ man -w git-secret
/usr/share/man/man7/git-secret.7
kitchen@c71479c4f76c:/opt/workspace$
```

The version of Debian that works is:

```
kitchen@c71479c4f76c:/opt/workspace$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)
Release:        9.4
Codename:       stretch
kitchen@c71479c4f76c:/opt/workspace$
```

The version of Ubuntu which doesn't is:

```
kitchen@ceddd8d3564c:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
kitchen@ceddd8d3564c:~$
```

Why don't the man pages install on Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you happen to have `dpkg` path exclusions on the Ubuntu system? Look at the output of `grep -r path-exclude /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg*` to find out.

Comment: aha! ```kitchen@ceddd8d3564c:~$ grep -r path-exclude /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg*
/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes:path-exclude=/usr/share/man/*
/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes:path-exclude=/usr/share/doc/*``

Comment: `sudo rm /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes` fixes it. @StephenKitt please submit as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `dpkg` configuration on your Ubuntu system, namely the `path-exclude=/usr/share/man/*` directive in `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes`, instructs `dpkg` to *not* install manpages.

If you do want to install manpages, remove the corresponding line and install the package again.